# What is the meaning of the word "rien" in the sentence “Ne vous préoccupez de rien !”?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms, négation

Does this sentence:

> *Ne vous préoccupez de **rien*** !

mean:

> Do not worry about **anything!** ≠ Worry about **nothing**!

or:

> Do not worry about **the smallest things**! (Those things are **nothing** important.)

?

I’m not sure how to interpret the ***rien*** bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ne ... rien* = *not ... anything* or *nothing*

> je ne mange rien  = I do not eat anything

**then it means:**

**Do not worry about anything!**

*ne* ... *guère* = *not ... much*  or *not a lot*

> je ne mange guère = I do not eat a lot

ne ... pas = not

ne ... plus = not ... anymore

ne ... jamais = never

Answer (score 2):

It means “worry about nothing!” [i.e. “I am taking care of everything” or possibly, “leave me alone”, depending on context]

“Un rien” can also mean “something small” but not in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

To understand better what *rien* means, knowing its etymology helps.

*Rien* comes from the Latin *res* that means "thing, affair, stuff": *Res publica*  → public matters.

The fact it is essentially used in negative sentences shifted its perceived meaning (nothing) to be exactly the opposite of its original one (something).

*Ne vous préoccupez de rien !* literally translates to "Don't worry about anything!"

Answer (score 2):

The following suggestions are not literal translations at all (and only address the meaning of "rien" indirectly by using its opposite, "everything"), but if I saw “Ne vous préoccupez de rien” used as a slogan for a hotel, travel agency, or even a DUI law firm, I would take it to mean:

> “Relax, we’ll take care of everything”

or

> “Relax, just leave everything to us”

Regarding your second interpretation (essentially: “Don’t sweat the small stuff”) it occurs to me that it is not really that illogical, but it would require a “pas” to make the “rien” mean what you propose in Option #2 (otherwise, it’s just part of the “ne/rien” construction).
It would also require some extra words and letters (including the pluralization of “rien”) to make it an understandable, if not idiomatic, way of saying “Don’t sweat the small stuff”:

“Ne vous préoccupez **pas** de**s petits** rien**s**.”

It would still, however, not be as idiomatic as:

“Ne vous préoccupez **pas** des détails” (with "rien" not present at all) or better still

“[Ne] t'inquiètes pas pour les détails/ [Ne te] casse pas la tête avec les détails." (which wouldn't use either "préoccuper" or "rien")

Answer (score 1):

In that particular context, it means not to worry about a single thing (nothing). Even though it could translate into `anything`, anything would imply nothing as well because **not** worrying about anything , is not worrying at all.

> anything = a thing of any kind

Do not worry about `anything` = do not worry about a thing of any kind = don't worry at all